# How can i avoid logging jersey WebApplicationExceptions?

Tags: java, jersey

Using jersey, i throw a WebApplicationException with a 503, indicating that my service is unavailable (because some downstream service is unavailable).

When this happens, i get logging that looks like the below, with a huge stack trace.

```
[exec] SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 503 (Service Unavailable)
[exec] javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
...
```

I don't really want this logging, since it actually ends up tying up the server's threads due to too much logging. Eg, i find many threads stuck in the below. Is there any way to just tell jersey to not log anything, or at least not log the stack trace? Note that i do want this logging for other error codes, like a 500. Just not 503's.

```
at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:174)
- waiting to lock <0x00000000c30ef5e0> (a java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler)
at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:88)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:478)
at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:500)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:589)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.logException(ContainerResponse.java:509)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.onException(ContainerResponse.java:487)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapWebApplicationException(ContainerResponse.java:421)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException(ContainerResponse.java:399)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1418)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
```

Comment: What version of jersey are you using?

Comment: I want this logging, can't find out how to get it, arrrgh!

Comment: Is this logging actually going into a file, or is it just appearing on stdout?

Comment: If you are using jersey 1.x, you can disable tracing via a property in the Application: https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#FEATURE_TRACE . This should stop the exception stack trace logging. However, I am not 100% sure about this and I can't test at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to simply turn off all logging for that class. SLF4J provides an "OFF" level, which suppresses all logging.

In my Dropwizard config:

```
loggers:
  "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse": OFF
```

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but I couldn't handle those stack traces polluting my logs anymore.